# Spring JPA Hibernate - NullPointerException on commit

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I am getting a `NullPointerException` on commit of a fairly large object graph.  I know that my Spring configuration is correct because I am able to persist new entities and changes to existing entities fine.

I've tried setting my logging to TRACE/DEBUG all the way back to org.springframework and org.hibernate but haven't seen anything helpful. I've also turned on logging in Postgres and haven't seen anything there.

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone had luck with debugging these sorts of problems?
2. What levels of logging, and where (JVM, Postgres, etc.) have you used and had success with?

Thanks.

Comment: I typically just throw in an exception breakpoint on NullPointerException (although there tend to be a few "expected" NPE in any given application, I just step past those) until I hit the exception.  I then work backwards through the 3rd party source trying to figure out how it got in that state.

Comment: The question lacks details: (a) no full stacktrace (b) no relevant code fragments (c) no specific version numbers of libraries used, therefore I'm voting to close this question as "too broad".